# Postgresql install error, using brew

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I tried to install PostgreSQL using `brew` and this error gets thrown up on my MacBook Pro:

```
undefined method `rebuild' for #<BottleSpecification:0x007f951aac98e0>
```

I have already used the command `brew doctor` and assigned admin rights to the brew directory and none of this helps!

Comment: Posting the entire error could be helpful to give the error a bit of context. What OS X version? Are you able to install anything else using brew? Is it only PostgreSQL which fails? Have you tried `brew update`? Have you followed the [troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting)? Try `cd $(brew --repo); git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master; brew update`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem with this command

```
brew update -v;
```